# Typescript: Loop through unknown object

Tags: typescript

I have an object for which I don't exactly know the format (users' CSV file). I need to loop through the keys to try to find specific keys and then access them. In this case I'm trying to import phone numbers, which can be referenced in the .csv file as `phoneNumbers1`, `phoneNumbers2`, and so on.

How can I remove the `//@ts-ignore` without being screamed at? :)

```
        const phoneNumbers = Object.keys(data)
          //@ts-ignore
          .filter((key) => key.includes("phoneNumbers") && !!data[p])
          //@ts-ignore
          .map((p) => ({ number: data[p], type: PHONE_TYPES.OFFICE }));
```

When trying to access the information via `data[p]`, I'm getting the error below:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 
expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'object'.
```

PS: `data` is an `object` type, since I only know at this stage that it is de facto an object (parse was successful), but I don't know what's can be coming in.

I know I could use `any` or other workarounds, but I would like to know if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` isn't really the type you want here. The `object` type is more or less an empty object like `{}`, so doesn't allow you to access keys that don't exist.

You probably want a type like `Record<string, unknown>` instead. This is an object type that will you allow to access any string key, and will return an `unknown` type.

Though if this is CSV data, then `Record<string, string>` may be appropriate if you know all the values are strings.

Then this code will compile without error:

```
const data: Record<string, unknown> = { whoKnows: 'foo' }

const phoneNumbers = Object.keys(data)
  .filter((key) => key.includes("phoneNumbers") && !!data[key])
  .map((p) => ({ number: data[p] }));
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDASgU1AJzgHmhwEswBzAGhgFcwBrMEAdzAD4YBeGAbxiYAsQAaUZMIaAOQAzECAkwAvgCgloSLAAOgsJgBy1ALYAjTDgicYAeSMArbFAB0dTAE8IACkTIAlEpgwHKWIAGyhTd3dnF29OdiiHUmBg6jhMDwAiLXA9QxMzdJiAMkKYAEJSrwQAbSiAXV9-BwMEDQiNGI52d14wXNM0SqqNWsVvbwBuIA)